# Core Bluetooth CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey could have some custom data?

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-bluetooth

im trying to send some data between and android and iOS device with BLE, but I need to send some custom information on the side of iOS to android , I already try almost all the keys that the CBCentralManager provides , but I try to send some string with the key  CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey  but nothing happens,anyone to know how to send information in that key?

in advance I try to have that information without connection.

this is the function that I use to try to make that part that I explain before.

```
 func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
    
    if peripheral.state == .poweredOn{
        
        let data = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: hardCodeUUID, properties: [.read], value: userName.data(using: .utf8), permissions: [.readable])
     
    
        peripherialManager.startAdvertising([ CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey:"Jael2522",CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey:userName.data(using: .utf8),CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey:[CBUUID(string: "Jose")]])
        
        
        let serialService = CBMutableService(type: hardCodeUUID, primary: true)

        serialService.characteristics = [data]
        peripherialManager.add(serialService)
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey is readonly in iOS. The only things you can directly advertise are the local name and the list of service UUIDs (neither of which are guaranteed to be advertised, though they will be when your app is in the foreground if they can fit in the packet).

In order to reliably send data between the devices, you need one side to actually connect and read or write to characteristics.

Comment: Rob will it be possible to send some information in service data or is it not possible?

Comment: No. That's CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey, which is readonly in iOS. The only things you can directly advertise are the local name and the list of service UUIDs.